# Terminal window not working Ubuntu after uninstalling Python folders

Tags: python, ubuntu

I tried removing my python2.7 and python3 folders from `/usr/local/bin` by using a command:

```
sudo rm -rf python2.7
```

and

```
sudo rm -rf python3
```

Later my terminal is not opening. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 9):

I was having the same issue when I updated python to 3.6 and selected alternative as python3.6, but when I reverted the option to the python3.5, terminal started working again:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python3
```

The following message popped up:

```
There are 2 choices for the alternative python3 (providing /usr/bin/python3).

  Selection    Path                Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/python3.6   2         auto mode
* 1            /usr/bin/python3.5   1         manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/python3.6   2         manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

I selected `1` and it started working.

You can use Virtual Studio Code or any IDE to open it's internal Terminal and run the command to fix the common Terminal.

Comment: how can i run the command when my terminal is not opening?

Comment: @ShoaibIqbal hey install terminator or use x term if your terminal is not working

Answer (score 4):

You do not specify how deep your problem goes here. You also don't mention what you have already tried and which solutions do not work.

Ubuntu depends on Python, so removing it messes up with your system. When you force rm to remove Python, obviously you don't get a warning what the effects will be, but doing this in via `apt` would have shown you. A similar issue is also discussed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/187227/i-run-sudo-apt-get-remove-python2-7-can-i-restore-my-ubuntu-now).

Here there are some solutions:

- You can reinstall your Ubuntu.
- You can recover using live CD using `chroot`
- Try to run some other package manager like Synaptic (if they are installed) and reinstall Python 2.7
- Manually download Python 2.7 package (and its dependencies), and manually install them using `dpkg` (bypassing APT, which requires Python). You can press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to run an application.
- Can you go to the virtual consoles by pressing  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>F6</kbd> (you can get back to the window manager by  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>)? If yes, then you can login with your user pass and see if you can run `sudo apt-get update` & `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop` or `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python2.7`
- I would also have a look in `.bashrc` as it is loaded every time you run the terminal.

Answer (score 2):

1. Install PyCharm.
2. Open PyCharm terminal.
3. Run `sudo apt-get update`.
4. Run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`.

Answer (score 1):

I will list what caused my problem and how I fixed it.
Python version in my terminal was 2.7 and to upgrade it to 3+.
You might have got this message as well

```
Error while finding module specification for 'virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'virtualenvwrapper')
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks.

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3 and that PATH is
set properly.
```

It didn't seem to have worked. Then terminal wasn't opening at all. After going through many stackoverflow answers I couldn't figure out. At the end let me tell what I did :

1. Change python version in ~/.bashrc file.

```
vi ~/.bashrc
# change version
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3.6
source ~/.bashrc
```

2. 

```
sudo update-alternatives install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.6 2
sudo update-alternatives --config python
```

The number 2 is user choice in my case there were two python versions.
After executing both commands it will show a list of versions
Select the python version from .bashrc file in auto mode

For me this worked!!!

Answer (score 0):

1 CTRL + ALT + F1

2 cp ~/.bashrc ~/.bashrc.bak

3 cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/

4 source ~/.bashrc

if terminal not working with  CTRL + ALT + F1, try to change the content of .bashrc manually

Answer (score 0):

In my case

```
sudo apt-get install language-pack-en-base
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
locale -a
export LC_ALL="en.utf-8"
sudo nano /etc/default/locale
```

and it shoud be

```
#  File generated by update-locale
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
```

outherwise

```
sudo apt install dconf-cli
dconf reset -f /org/gnome/terminal
sudo apt-get remove gnome-terminal
sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal
sudo locale-gen --purge
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales



reboot
```

Answer (score 0):

GO to Setting -> Region & Language -> Login screen -> change language to English(United State) and restart

Before Change

[image]

After change
[image]

Hope your issue fixed !!!